# Unfair probabilistic game

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have several boys, and they decide who is going to start the game. Each of them simultaneously show 0, or 1, $\dots$, or 5 fingers. After that we sum all terms(let's say, we get $N$), and then start counting $N$ times around the circle from the boy whom we chose before(zero number corresponds to him). The guy, on whom counting stops, starts the game. For what number of boys the game will be fair? I think, it means, that probability for each boy to start will be the same.

Comment: I don't understand how you win the game.

Comment: @Ian:
This process defines, who starts the game. A game goes after and is not  important here.

Comment: So really, the winner is the $N$th boy, where the zeroth boy is arbitrarily chosen at the start (and announced?), and you count periodically. The rest of the information is then superfluous because it pertains to an irrelevant subsequent game.

Comment: @Ian:
What's wrong? When you simultaneously show fingures, sum all numbers and go counting, all of the boys could win. I need a number of guys for whom we get equal probability.

Comment: I'm confused too. When you mean fair, do you mean equal chance of getting to start???

Comment: Of course, I announced it in the problem too.

Comment: The original post says "they decide who is going to start" some game by the stated process: each boy shows 1 to 5 fingers, the number of fingers is summed, to give "N" and then we count N places (not "N times around") "from the boy whom we chose before".  So how, exactly is "the boy whom we chose before"?  Once you have chosen that boy, why do another procedure to choose another boy?

Comment: Here is my full understanding of the game. You have $B$ boys, labeled $0,1,\dots,B-1$. You start from boy $0$. The $B$ boys collectively choose a number $N$ between $0$ and $5B$, inclusive, by simultaneously showing fingers. The winner is the boy whose label is $N$ mod $B$ (which is announced to the boys). So for example if $B=7,N=24$ then boy $3$ wins. Are there any errors in this description?

Comment: @lan:
I think, that you've given right interpretation of my words. Thanks and sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 1):

If $m>1$ is the number of participants, and each one chooses a number between $0$ and $5$ with equal probability, then the following program computes the probability of each participant being selected.

```
function probs = whostarts(m)
  % Probabilities of each outcome for one participant.
  pb1 = ones(1,6)/6;
  % Compute probabilities of each outcome by repeated convolution.
  pbd = pb1;
  for k = 2:m
    pbd = conv(pbd,pb1);
  end
  % Probability of each congruence class.
  probs = zeros(1,m);
  for k = 0:5*m
    r = mod(k,m);
    probs(r+1) = probs(r+1) + pbd(k+1);
  end
end
```

For $m \leq 3$ the game is fair, but after that it becomes progressively more unfair as $m$ increases, at least for small values of $m$, with the exception of $m=6$.

For $m \in \{25,50,100\}$, for instance, the probabilities look like this:

[image]

Comment: Why would all totals be equally likely? It seems that there should be some kind of multinomial-type distribution: all *sequences* are equally likely but the number of sequences with a given sum varies for different sums. (This also assumes that the boys just choose numbers completely at random, which might not be the optimal strategy for their position. But now we're getting into game theory...)

Comment: @Ian Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake.  Take two should be a significant improvement.

Comment: Interesting, you can also sort of see this by considering $B$ large enough that $\sqrt{B} \ll 0.5B$, in which case the sum is typically in between $2B$ and $3B$ (by mean/variance considerations) and so the modulus tends to concentrate around the modulus of the mean i.e. around $0.5B$. This also explains the Gaussian shape in your plots especially near $0.5B$. Far away from $0.5B$ you see a significant contribution from multiple values of the sum, so the profile looks different (until $B$ gets even larger).